# discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'change_presence' Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

When trying to change the presence in the bot class of discord.py I get the error that the change_presence attribute is not in discord.ext.comands

In "on ready" is located the change of presence and description that it has put on, I try to change what it has but it does not let me do it because of the error that takes me

```
from pathlib import Path

import discord
from discord.ext import commands




class MusicBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cogs = [p.stem for p in Path(".").glob("./bot/cogs/*.py")]
        super().__init__(command_prefix=self.prefix, case_insensitive=True)

def setup(self):
    print("Yuki abrio sus ojitos...")

    for cog in self._cogs:
        self.load_extension(f"bot.cogs.{cog}")
        print(f" Loaded `{cog}` cog.")

    print("Yuki se esta visitendo...")

def run(self):
    self.setup()

    with open("data/token.0", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        TOKEN = f.read()

    print("Yuki se esta levantando :3...")
    super().run(TOKEN, reconnect=True)

async def shutdown(self):
    print("Closing connection to Discord...")
    await super().close()

async def close(self):
    print("Closing on keyboard interrupt...")
    await self.shutdown()

async def on_connect(self):
    print(f" Connected to Discord (latency: {self.latency*1000:,.0f} ms).")

async def on_resumed(self):
    print("Bot resumed.")

async def on_disconnect(self):
    print("Bot disconnected.")

async def on_error(self, err, *args, **kwargs):
    raise

async def on_command_error(self, ctx, exc):
    raise getattr(exc, "original", exc)

async def on_ready(self):
    self.client_id = (await self.application_info()).id
    print("Yuki ya desperto uwu")

async def on_ready(self):
    activity = discord.Game(name="", type=3)
    await commands.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)

async def prefix(self, bot, msg):
    return commands.when_mentioned_or("<")(bot, msg)

async def process_commands(self, msg):
    ctx = await self.get_context(msg, cls=commands.Context)

    if ctx.command is not None:
        await self.invoke(ctx)

async def on_message(self, msg):
    if not msg.author.bot:
        await self.process_commands(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

`await commands.change_presence()` returns an error because
`commands` has to be replaced with a `commands.Bot` instance.